# swfobject to embed the swf in my html or PHP

Tags: php, flash

I am using PHP language and I have a swf file . I am using swf file for the first time so I don't know how to use swfobject to embed the swf in my html or PHP . I just know how to use php but I don't know anything about swf embedding . I can't give you the code also because I am not able to figure out the way to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple way of embedding swf file in HTML

```
<object width="100" height="100">
    <param name="movie" value="file.swf">
    <embed src="file.swf" width="100" height="100">
    </embed>
</object>
```